# Help understanding the result obtained in a paper concerning renormalization group

Tags: mathematical-physics

I am reading the paper [Large financial crashes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9704127;) and I noticed that it uses the renormalization group (RG) formalism. Here are some excerpts from the paper:

[image]

It continues by writing that

> we notice that the solution (3) of the RG equation (2) together with
> (1) and the linear approximation $\phi(x)=\lambda x$ can be rewritten
> as $$ \frac{d F(x)}{d \log x}=\alpha F(x), $$

Anyway, I tried to obtain this result by calculating explicitly the derivative of $F(x)$ with respect $\log x$ but I came across a different outcome:
$$ \frac{d F(x)}{d \log x}=x\frac{d F(x)}{d x}=\alpha F(x)+C (\omega - \lambda x) \sin\left(\lambda x - \omega \log x\right)$$
Could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong please?